# Burninate: badcode

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

Yes, we have a [badcode](/questions/tagged/badcode) tag on Stack Overflow.  I didn't realize it until just a moment ago, either.

There's like sixteen questions, most of which can be reasonably retagged without any loss in quality...but I would propose that this tag be terminated with extreme prejudice.

Comment: I'm keeping a few of these open in tabs, and I'll note the ones that are better candidates for deletion than editing in a moment.

Comment: Bah. Ken White keeps beating me to the edit by a second or so.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: Good. It's usually me who gets beat by a second or so (mostly when answering). :-)

Comment: Well...that went quickly.  There's still a handful of these that could use delete votes, though.  I'll be voting accordingly.

Comment: Oooh... can I post some of my 'bad code' here to be burninated?

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn:  No, I'd rather burninate the bad coder.  Remember:  bad code can always be rewritten.  ;)

Comment: I'd like to take this opportunity to publicize [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).